# Regex (Python) - Match everything before desired word

Tags: python, regex

I simply want to strip my file of every character and carriage return etc before the first appearance of the string "From:".

text example -

"File name 123
file date xxxxx

other text

From: john@example.com ...."

I can't seem to just grab everything before "From:" which i thought would be a simple line but no. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try this regex,

```
(?s).*?From(.*)
```

And replace it with \1

Explanation:

```
(?s) --> Enables . to match new lines
.*?From --> captures anything before first occurrence of From
(.*) --> Matches rest of the input and stores it in group 1
```

Demo, https://regex101.com/r/Q8eFKL/2

Answer (score 0):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
>>> re.findall('^(.*)(?=From:)', your_text)
```

This will prevent it from matching patterns that don't contain "From:", and thus may not be formatted like you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Dot(.) matches everything other than a linebreak. So my approach would be:

```
(.|\n|\r)*(?=From:)
```

- ***1st Alternative .***

  - . matches any character (except for line terminators)
- ***2nd Alternative \n***

  - \n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
- ***3rd Alternative \r***

  - \r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
- ***Positive Lookahead (?=From:)***

  - Assert that the Regex below matches From: matches the characters
    From: literally (case sensitive)